# C++ виртуальная шаблонная функция(псевдо)

Tags: c++

Итак, создать такую функцию нельзя, знаю. Однако мне очень требуется. В связи с этим интересуюсь, есть ли какие-нибудь обходные примеры? Пока кроме такого ничего не придумал:

```
class A
{
protected:
    virtual void _func(const char*) = 0; // метод для класса B
    virtual void _func(float) = 0; // метод для класса C
public:
    template<class T> void func(T e) { this->_func(e); }

};

class B : public A
{
private:
    void _func(const char* i) {};
protected:
    void _func(float i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    void _func(float i) { std::cout << "тест" << std::endl; };
protected:
    void _func(const char* i) { std::cout << i << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.func(14.4); // вызовем _func(float) из B

    C c;
    c.func("Привет"); // вызовем _func(int) из C
    c.func(14.9);

    return 0;
}
```

Однако недостатки очевидны: приходиться переопределять ненужную виртуальную функцию в каждом классе, которой пользоваться не придется. При этом, можно каждому дочернему классу передать аргумент, который мы не хотим передавать(показано в методе *void _func(float i) { std::cout << "тест" << std::endl; };* )
Есть ли более элегантные решения? Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем их объявлять в A? Эти функции не присущи всем потомкам A, правда? Так почему такое решение? Вы хотите работать с ними через указатель на A? тогда вы строите иерархию, где потомкам A в принципе присуще обе функции...

Comment: В идеале, хотелось бы, чтобы каждый потомок мог вызвать метод и передать ему свой тип(виртуальные шаблонные функции, которые низя)

Comment: Понимаете, я, наверное, не очень могу донести свою мысль... Но вы определяете класс `A`, как класс, способный передавать и `char*`, и `float`, а раз любой его потомок ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ `A`, то он тоже обязан уметь это. Поскольку он есть `A`. Так что либо потомки должны уметь все, что умеет предок, либо надо изменить саму иерархию - ибо сам дизайн неверен...

Comment: Понимаете, ваш вопрос - я тут хочу забить гвоздь кулаком. Я поясняю - лучше молотком. Вы сначала возражаете - в идеале хотелось бы кулаком. Я опять пытаюсь пояснить, что молотком оно как-то способнее... И вы спрашиваете - может, действительно лучше молотком? Ну понятно, что молотком!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не очень понял, чего вы хотите добиться в примере, но если говорить о виртуальных шаблонных функциях - она не может быть виртуальной, однако шаблонный класс может иметь виртуальную функцию. На определенном этапе инстанцирования шаблонов типы, которые можно передавать в шаблонную псевдовиртуальную функцию становятся известными (иначе бы и смысла не было), а значит ничего не мешает создать кортеж указателей на такие шаблонные классы с обычными виртуальными функциями, конкретизированные нужными вам типами.

```
template<class T>
class Visitor{
   virtual void visit(T& value);
};

template<class... Ts>
class Storage{
     std::tuple<Visitor<Ts>*...> m_visitors;

     public:
     template<std::size_t I, class T>
     void visit(T& value){
        auto visitor = std::get<I>(m_visitors);
        visitor->visit(value);
     }
};
```

Тут возникает проблема с инициализацией визитёров - на каждый тип нужен свой экземпляр, но можно решить проблему при помощи обобщенных лямбд.

В `Storage::visit` `I` и `T` на самом деле связаны, но без метопрограммирования одно из другого получить не получится.

Другой вариант - передавать в качестве аргумента виртуальной функции `std::variant` с допустимыми типами, а уже реализация виртуальной функции решит, что делать с конкретными типами. Если типы-аргументы имеют разный размер, в `std::variant` можно передавать ссылки, а не значения (оборачивая их в `std::reference_wrapper`), или можно использовать `boost::variant`, который поддерживает обычные ссылки.

```
template<class... Ts>
class Storage{
  std::tuple<Ts...> m_values;

  virtual void visit(boost::variant<Ts&...> ref){}

public:
  Storage(std::tuple<Ts...> values): m_values(values) {}

  void callVisit(){
      std::apply([this](auto&... v) mutable{
        auto visit = [this](auto& v){ this->visit(v); return 0;};
        int unused[] = {visit(v)...}; // Вызов this->visit для всех значений кортежа
      }, m_values);
  }
};

template<class... Ts>
class StorageImpl: public Storage<Ts...>{

   void visit(boost::variant<Ts&...> ref) override {
       boost::apply_visitor([](auto& value){
          // тут по сути тело шаблонной виртуальной функции, value - шаблонный аргумент
       } ,ref);
   }
public:
   using Storage<Ts...>::Storage;
};
```

Ничего не мешает передавать два и более аргумента при таком подходе, главное - так или иначе узнать типы, допустимые для передачи.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш дизайн сейчас примерно соответствует такому: абстрактный класс *Животное*, в который вы одновременно запихиваете функции *Летать* и *Плавать*, и далее вы хотите из него порождать, например, *Орла* и *Дельфина*. Но это неверный подход. Где, в каком месте у вас "Животное вообще" должно летать? или плавать? Да, есть какие-нибудь летучие рыбы или там утки - но если вы поступаете так, то ограничиваете понятие животных только теми, кто может летать и плавать одновременно.

Если у вас будет код, который вы хотите - с **запретом** летать в производном классе, например - то к чему приведет ваш (вполне корректный) вызов через указатель на базовый абстрактный класс типа `Животное->Летать` при передаче ему какого-то *Тигра*? К ошибке *времени выполнения*.

В самом лучшем случае нужно дополнить иерархию абстрактными классами, скажем, *Птицы* и *Водоплавающие*, а уже потом на них строить конкретные классы. (Кстати, тогда летающие рыбы будут получаться множественным наследованием.) Не надо идти против природы.

Если вы решите свою проблему, *запрещая* передачу не того аргумента - вы получите новую проблему - обработку ошибки передачи неверного аргумента *во время работы программы*, в то время как при правильной иерархии вылавливанием такой ошибки может заняться компилятор.

Если и это непонятно - умываю руки, делайте квадратное колесо, а потом спрашивайте, как написать трактор, который будет способен тащить телегу с такими колесами...

**Update**

Судя по всему, вы таки решили делать квадратные колеса :)
Ну что ж, понимание, что затыкание дыр не ведет ни к чему хорошему, придет позже, с опытом.